# Xcode 5.1 access the app itself

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I began coding Objective C last night and i made my first basic Cocoa app for my Macbook Air.
I have built it and everything, but i can't find the executable app in the project folder?

I am using 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. Then find the folder for your program.

Comment: Won't it also be in a Debug or Release sub folder there? (Baring changes to the build settings to have some deployment path)

Comment: @uchuugaka My answer was to get the OP in the starting point to find what was needed.

Answer (score 1):

A faster way would be:

In the Project Navigator (if it's not shown: cmd + 1 or View -> Navigators -> ...) expand the folder Products, then right-click on the ".app" and then "Show in Finder"

Answer (score 0):

Build data doesn't go in the project because (i) it's logically a separate thing; (ii) therefore you want to keep it in a separate place; and (iii) keeping it in the same place will usually confuse the issue of source control, either your repository or you.

Apple's preferred approach is that you Build -> Archive, which will (unless you've specified otherwise) always be a release build, then export as a .app or publish to the App Store from the Organiser.

That'll keep that version of the build with all symbolication data on your machine until you delete it. So you can send exactly the same build to someone else, definitely decide any crash logs that come back, etc.